# Change style of line endings with eclipse code formatter

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, code-formatting, line-endings

I am working with windows, using IntelliJ and the eclipse code formatter.
My problem is, that I want to have only Unix style line endings in my projekt. IntelliJ has the option to use that, but if I rebuild my project, the code formatter changes every line in every file and I get the windows line ending style.
I already searched [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-soft-arch/9.6.1?topic=SS8PJ7_9.6.1/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/formatter/DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.html) for an option to change the style, but I coudn't find any option that fits for my problem.
Does someone has an idea how to solve my problem

Comment: How did you change the line separator in IntelliJ? I'm not sure I get what the eclipse code formatter has to do with this?

Comment: @Abby In the settings --> Code style you can change it. I am building the project with gradle and I am using the code formatter for some changes there. After I build the project every file has the windows line ending. If I disable the code formatter I dont have that problem

Comment: When exactly do the line separators change to Windows (`\r\n`)? After building the project with Gradle? After formatting with the IntelliJ formatter? Or after formatting with the Eclipse formatter? Can you edit your question to contain a clear list of steps you took, indicating at what point the line separators changed?